# CSS ball position

Tags: css, position

I have a title `<h2>` with `<small>` and I would like to add a colored ball in front of my title.

```
<span ng-class="{'greenBall' : order.state == 'Created'}">
<h2> Finalize <small>Some text</small> </h2>
```

Here is my css to create the "ball"

```
.greenBall{
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(90, 189, 90, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;}
```

The probleme is that the ball is above the title and not in front.
I tried to use `display:inline` but the "ball" need to be in `block`.

Any idea ?

Comment: display: inline-block ?

Comment: Can't you simply position it absolutely?

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud on span ? or a div that contains h2 + span ?

Comment: @TreeTree It will cause some problems when resizing the window, won't it ?

Comment: On both: http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/gbyOyQ

Comment: @Weedoze Maybe it will, but that's not a requirement in your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be what you're looking for, but in this instance you could just use the :before selector.

```css
h2:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(90, 189, 90, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2> Finalize <small>Some text</small> </h2>
```

I believe the size of the "ball" is based on the size of the font and the text within the content rule. Note that the color is the same as the background-color, there is actually text in that bubble.

Comment: You can control the size of the ball with `width` and `height` if you set it to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yeah, that works and is much nicer than adding text into the content rule, you can leave it as content:'' and it will obey the dimensions specified.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full context or knowledge as to the end result or purpose of this particular code, I will take a stab at building on top of @ferr's answer. Since the original question was in regards to layout; I would recommend abstracting the layout from the text object a bit further, in order to implement more control over different use cases and scenarios.
i.e. Say you decide the 'ball' should be top aligned, bottom aligned, or middle aligned, or you want the 'ball' to be a square, or the text size changes, et cetera. I included notes in the code in relation to this.

```
<div class="heading">
   <div class="heading-text">
      <h2>Finalize <small>Some text</small></h2>
   </div>
</div>

    .heading {
  font-size: 0; /* removes trailing white space for inline-block display of child nodes */
  line-height: 0; /* establishes a reset for auto line-height and can now be set on individual child nodes */
}

.heading-text {
  font-size: 20px; /* re-establishes according to the base object reset */
}

.heading-text > * {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 6px; /* adjust accordingly */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading-text:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: .5em;
  height: .5em;
  vertical-align: middle; /* this can now control the vertical alignment of the 'ball' */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(90, 189, 90); /* legacy fallback */
  background-color: rgba(90, 189, 90, 1);
}
```